# How to display the different words in 2 sentences? in python preferably

Tags: python, string

"this is my name"
"this is my first name"

I want to print the term "first"
I just want to print the different term.Preferably python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using list comprehension as:

```
x = "this is my name".split()
y = "this is my first name".split()
diff = [y1 for y1 in y if y1 not in x]
print(diff)
```